# Computing mutual information for two lists of real numbers in Python

Tags: python, entropy, information-theory

I need to compute the [Mutual Information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information) (MI) between two lists of values for two different features in a dataset, for example,

```
X=[0.85, 0.82, 0.21, 0., 0.93] and Y=[ 0.21, 0.82, 0.88, 0.95, 0. ], in Python (i.e. MI(X,Y))
```

I know how to compute this measure for categorical variables in Python (by simple counting), but I have no idea how to compute the MI for real value variables.

Unfortunately, I don't have a strong mathematical base and I just need to achieve the correct final output. So, I have two  questions:

1) How should I compute MI for two random sets of random values?

2) Is there any straightforward implementation of computing MI for real value variables?

I find some implementations like [this](https://gist.github.com/GaelVaroquaux/ead9898bd3c973c40429), but I'm not sure whether these implementations generate the desired output or not.

Please provide your solutions by presenting your code if you can. Thanks!

Comment: Where does the continuous come from? I only see discrete numbers.

Comment: @frankyjuang Maybe it was my mistake. I edit my question, I think I should say real value variables instead of continuous variables.

Comment: The implementation you linked uses the Kraskov estimator, which is exactly what you want. Read the paper: Kraskov, Stoegbauer, Grassberger (2004?) Estimating mutual information. It's an easy read.